# Code will not work as function but does in the main code. (Python, pygame)

Tags: python, function, timer, pygame

I have been experimenting with pygame and I have run into a problem. The code I have written with the intent of creating a timing based event, will only work outside of a function. Am I missing something?

```
def drop_obs(obs_list, timer):

    timer += clock.tick(60)/1000
    if timer >= 2:
        x_obs_pos = WIDTH/2
        y_obs_pos = random.randint(0, HEIGHT - block_size)
        obs_list.append([x_obs_pos, y_obs_pos])
        timer = 0
```

If I paste the code inside the main code it works however.
(In regards to this code, the goal is just to append a new x and y position to an already existing list ever time the clock ticks)

Comment: Except for issues of scope, there's no difference between if code is in a function or not. Please describe what you expect to happen and what's actually happening.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then try adding more details to your question.

Comment: I'm going to guess though that your issue is that `time += . . .` isn't affecting the actual timer variable being passed in. If you want to alter a `timer` variable that exists when calling the function, you'd need to either make `timer` global, or return it from the function and reassign it at the callsite.

Answer (score 1):

Try passing pre-defined global variables as the arguments for the `drop_obs()` function

```py
timer1 = 0 
list1 = [] #can be pre-emptied or pre-filled
[...] #the other part of code

def drop_obs(obs_list,timer):
    timer += clock.tick(60)/1000
    if time >=2:
        x_obs_pos = WIDTH/2
        y_obs_pos = random.randint(0,HEIGHT - block_size)
        obs_list.append([x_obs_pos, y_obs_pos])
        timer = 0

drop_obs(list1,timer1)
```

Also if `x_obs_pos` and `y_obs_pos` are local variables (i.e. they are defined in a function) then you need to globalize it by using the statement `global x_obs_pos` and `global y_obs_pos`

Comment: If their problem really is `timer1` not changing outside of the function, this won't fix it. You'd need to alter `timer1` directly, or return the new value of `timer` from the function. The code in the answer is essentially what they already have.